# Inverse function with sets

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I have function $f: A \rightarrow B$ and a subset $X \subseteq A$.

I want to prove (or possibly disprove) these statements.

(1) $f^{-1}(f(X)) = X$

(2) $f(f^{-1}(f(X))) = f(X)$

At first I thought that both statements were true because

$f^{-1}$ and $f$ simply cancel out each other but that seems too

obvious and does not look like a correct approach.

Are both statements indeed true? or is there something I am missing?

Comment: I dislike the $f^{-1}$ notation for preimage for exactly this reason. Try to not think about cancellation and instead break the definitions down. If $f(X)$ is the set of all elements in $B$ mapped to from $X$, and then you take the preimage of that, must you get merely $X$?

Comment: It is true in general that $f^{-1}(f(X))\supset X$, but equality iff $f$ is injective,

Comment: Bear in mind $f$ may not be one-to-one and $f^{-1}$ notation is *NOT* a function.  If $f(x) = x^2$ for example then $f^{-1}(\{4\})= \{-2,2\}$ and $f^{-1}(\{-25\}) = \emptyset$.

Comment: So consider $f(x) = x^2$ and $X=\{3,6,-4\}$ then $f(X)=\{9,36,16\}$ and $f^{-1}(f(X)) = f^{-1}(\{9,36,16\} =\{-3,3,-6,6,-4,4\}$.  But think hard about 2)....

Comment: (2) is definitely true though.